# R, properly using the paste function

Tags: r

This loop properly creates 13 df's named bond1,...,bond13 and assigns them the values from function1. Now I need to create 13 more DF's named spread1, ..., spread13 using function2 and two other df's. One of these is fixed for all 13 spreads (DF_B) but for spreadi I need bondi and the second line in the code gives me an error of the following: 
"Loading required package: tcltk
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such table: bond)"

```
for(i in 1:13) 
{
  assign(paste("bond", i, sep = ""), function1(DF_A))
  assign(paste("spread", i, sep = ""), function2(DF_B, paste("bond", i, sep = "")))
}
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like your `function2` is the problem, not `paste` or the loop.

Comment: @Thomas, the problem is that `bondi` is not getting passed, but `"bondi"`

Comment: In general, if you are naming variables by number, you are doing something wrong, or at least sub optimally. I recommend Ricardo's alternative!

Comment: <selfish>Also, consider using (and contributing to!) the `maRketSim` package :-)</selfish>

Answer (score 9):

In function2 you are passing a string as the argument, not your actual data object.

Wrap `get(.)` around the paste function and you are all set:

```
function2(DF_B, get( paste("bond", i, sep = "") ) )
```

---

#### That being said, I would highly, highly recommend *against* this method.

Instead, use a `list`

```
bond <- vector("list", 13)
spread <- vector("list", 13)

for(i in 1:13) 
{
  bond[[i]]   <- function1(DF_A)
  spread[[i]] <- function2(DF_B, bond[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Also here you don't explain here why is "highly highly" against using `get`? I am not saying is good to use `get`, but personally I think that using a `for-loop` is more dangerous than using `get` here.

Comment: You think using a for loop is *more dangerous* than using get? I am curious as to what, for you, makes this so.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to avoid using a `for` loop here and avoid allocating memory in advance. Using `replicate` for example and keeping all your objects in a single list is the R-way to do things.

```
replicate(13,{
   bond   <- function1(DF_A)     ## Note here all your bonds are the same...
   spread <- function2(DF_B, bond)
   list(bond=bond,spread=spread)
},simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: clever use of `replicate`, but I'm not sure that this specific example is the "R-way" of doing things.  How straight forward do you suspect it is to access the results as opposed to having bond and spread in two separate objects. If you then assign them out of the results any efficiency gains made by avoiding memory allocation are thrown out the window.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I am not sure to get your point here. The result of replicate is a list. Say ll for example. I think 2 the objects(bond and spread are related) , so it is safer to access them like ll[1]$bond/ll[1]$spread than bond[1] and spread[1]. It is also the R-way to do because `replicate`(lapply family in general) here avoid any side effect that can be caused by `for`.