# Write an R Function that repeats data manipulating routines

Tags: r, function

Here is what I would expect the function to do:

```
datalist <- c("var1","var2",...)
my.function <- function(datalist){
   n        <- length(dlist)
   varnames <- paste("data", dlist, sep = ".")
   for (...) {   # for each var in 'varnames'
        ...      # grab each variable from some specific online dataset;
        ...      # do some basic data manipulation for each variable   
   }
   ...           # return all the results
}
```

The main difficulty for me is: 
(1) how to do the loop so the grabbed data could be properly temporally stored, and 
(2) how the multiple variables could be returned, after finishing the loop;

EDIT:

The loop can create variables I want during the loop, say VAR1 and VAR2, which were stored in the 'dlist' argument, but I cannot manipulate VAR1 or VAR2 in the function, dlist[1] or dlist[2] in the function would only give me a string but not the variable itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the answer to (1) and (2) is "use `list`s".   If you click on the `R` tag here in SO, and then click where it says "about" you will see a collection of documents and guides.  One of them is the R-intro. Have a look at the lists chapter.

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta, Sorry I might not make it clear. The loop can create variables I want during the loop, say VAR1 and VAR2, which were stored in the 'dlist' argument, but I cannot manipulate VAR1 or VAR2 in the function, dlist[1] or dlist[2] in the function would only give me a string but not the variable itself.

Comment: Hi @L.J, please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201603/r-properly-using-the-paste-function/19201717#19201717)

Comment: You should provide us some data, concise instructions on what you're trying to achieve and expected result. That way, we can be very efficient at helping you.

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta, you are right. My question is in some sense too general at its form and not quite understandable at the first glance. Some specific example with data should be better. Sorry for the trouble caused, I am sure there must be some other/better way that can achieve the result I expected, tough I have no time to go through the details now. Many thanks for your assistance. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem and make the function work as I expected.

As I described in the question, the main problem in fact is how to manipulate the variables while VAR1 and VAR2 themselves are strings in the function.

*eval* combined with *as.name* should work:

```
eval(as.name(dlist[i]))
```